# Why do external links on Google Search Console vary so much from month to month

Tags: google-search-console, backlinks

I keep an eye on external links to my website that google reports in its webmaster dashboard for my blog (technical tipps).

According to that dashboard, my website has a wildly varying number of external links. I normally publish articles on a weekly basis. Nothing that would attract a lot of spam.

Stats:

- May 2347 external links
- June 1789
- July 1708
- August 1185

How should I read this report? Or what should I make of this information? Why would the number of external links decrease continuously?

Comment: Because they are aggregated, grouped, deduplicated, canonicalized and so on. Further reading is under https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9049606?hl=en#known_issues